# Access Run time error 6 Overflow

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that does a simple calculation but the numbers are very large.

Example:
xml 96276480
graphics 2931829760

I've declared the data types as Long and even did a CLng(Me.txtGraphics.value) but I'm still getting the over flow error
These numbers are coming from text boxes.
Here's my code:

```
Dim sgm As Long
Dim XML As Long
Dim prv As Long
Dim base As Long
Dim IETM As Long
Dim Graphics As Long
Dim total As Long
Dim pgCnt As Long
Const CXML = 2.5
Const CSGM = 6
Const CGraphic = 339
Dim pcSGM As Long
Dim pcXML As Long
Dim pcGraphic As Long

If Me.txtSGM.value = "" Then
  sgm = 0
Else
  sgm = Me.txtSGM.value
End If


If Me.txtXML.value = "" Then
  XML = 0
Else
  XML = Me.txtXML.value
End If

If Me.txtGraphics.value = "" Then
  Graphics = 0
Else
  Dim pics As Long
  pics = CLng(Me.txtGraphics.value)
  Graphics = CLng(pics)
End If

If Me.txtTotal.value = "" Then
  base = 0
Else
  base = Me.txtTotal.value
End If


prv = base


pcSGM = (CLng(sgm) / 1024) / CSGM
pcXML = (CLng(XML) / 1024) / CXML
pcGraphic = (CLng(Graphics) / 1024) / CGraphic


'total calculated newest SGM & XML values
total = (CLng(pcSGM)) + (CLng(pcXML)) + (CLng(pcGraphic))
```

Thank you for the help,
Max

Answer (score 6):

A long in VBA is a 32-bit signed integer (as opposed to a long in VB.Net, which is 64-bits). As such, the maximum value it can hold is  2147483647.

2931829760 is clearly larger, thus you get an overflow.

Either use `Decimal` and `CDec` instead of `Long` and `CLng` to cast them to decimals, or use `Double` and `CDbl` to cast them to doubles.

`CDbl` is likely faster, but can cause floating-point inaccuracy problems.

If you're sure your code will only be executed in the 64-bits variant of Access, you can also use `CLngLng`, which casts it to the `LongLong` data type, a 64-bits signed integer

Comment: I get a sub or function not defined when trying to use CLngLng. How should I be declaring it?

      Dim pics As Long
      pics = CLngLng(Me.txtGraphics.value)
      Graphics = pics

Comment: You need to `Dim something As LongLong` too. Also, I'd avoid `LongLong` unless you're the only user and you're sure you have 64-bits office. If `CLngLng` is undefined you're on 32-bits office and can't use the `LongLong` data type

Comment: I received error "User-defined type not defined". This is what I declared Dim lngGraphic As LongLong. My system is 64bit Office 2016

Comment: ... Your system may be 64 bits, but if you get that error, you're clearly using 32-bits office. You can see this in the task manager, if you're on Win 10 it'll say Microsoft Access (32 bit)

Comment: Dim all the Longs as _Variant_, and replace CLng with _CDec_ all over. That's it.

Comment: @Gustav Changing everything to Variant and then CDec worked thank you!